# How do I make my app start on phone startup?

Tags: android

I would like to perform some action on phone start up. Is there simply an intent that I can use a Receiver with? or is there more to it?

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fairly simple.

you can also refer [this](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/). Instead of starting the servie u will be starting the activity.