# Custom Intent Broadcast not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send a custom intent to my service that is based off IntentService but when I do context.sendBroadcast nothing seems to happen.  I've checked through the logcat logs and can't even see the intent resolution failing.

My service registration in my Android.xml is

```
  <service android:name=".Service.FbSlideShowService" android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.test.fbslide.UPDATE_WALLPAPER" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I'm trying to send the broadcast from a helper class on my activity thread and passing in context using, I've tried sending it in 2 ways:

```
    Intent changeWallpaperIntent = new Intent(mContext, FbSlideShowService.class);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(changeWallpaperIntent);
```

And

```
 Intent changeWallpaperIntent = new Intent(FbSlideShowService.UPDATE_WALLPAPER_INTENT, null);
 mContext.sendBroadcast(changeWallpaperIntent);
```

But the broadcast just doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sendBroadcast works when you have a `BroadcastReciever`. But what you have here is a `sevice`

```
<service android:name=".Service.FbSlideShowService" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.fbslide.UPDATE_WALLPAPER" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Your manifest entry tells that it is a `service`

You need to use `mContext.startService()` to start the service.

If you want to start a service when device boots you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369513/how-do-i-make-my-app-start-on-phone-startup/4369532#4369532).

Comment: D'oh misread the docs, thanks. I thought anything with intent filters could. Reread them and get it now :)